# How can I make glGetShaderInfoLog() return information?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to write some code for Android using the OpenGL ES 2.0 lib. I have run in to the bug that glGetShaderInfoLog() always returns the empty string. This is a know bug with no real fix.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588800/glgetshaderinfolog-returns-empty-string-android) post (last answer) does suggest a workaround (and I saw similar posts while googling), but I do not understand how it works. Could someone please explain what I should do to make glGetShaderInfoLog() return some information when the compilation process fails.

I am using Eclipse and the newest version of AndroidSDK.