# Could not compile shader, nothing in the log

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader, libgdx

I tried to run my game on Samsung Galaxy Gio S5660.
Some shaders compiled successfully and some not.
There is nothing relevant in the log though (ShaderProgram.getLog()).

**log:**

```
--From Fragment Shader:
--From Vertex Shader:
```

Is there a way to get more info about the error. Offline compilation ?

Comment: Do the shaders work on your desktop?  Do you have a `#version` pragma in your shader?  Its very odd to get no output from the compiler.  Try commenting out code to isolate the problem.

Comment: They work perfectly on my desktop GTX 560 and on my phone Mali-400MP. I don't have `#version` in my shader. I try to isolate the problem. Could the problem be in LibGDX, corrupting the log from GPU?

Comment: Definitely add a `#version`.  See http://renderingpipeline.com/2012/03/shader-model-and-glsl-versions/.  The Libgdx code is pretty simple, so unlikely to be corrupting the log: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShaderProgram.java

Comment: The logs are probably empty due to a bug in Android. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8965475/377710