# GLES20.glGetInfoLog() returns "" (android)

Tags: android, logging, compilation, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I'm (finally) upgrading a project I'm working on to openGL ES 2.0. I started by following the tutorial on the Android Developer website, which worked without a hitch. Now, I'm trying to implement this in my existing app, but it doesn't work. I tracked down the problem to compiling the shaders using glGetShaderiv() (which is oddly enough different than how it's described in the GLES 2.0 specifications - is that normal?), by adding this in my loadShader() method:

```
IntBuffer temp = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, type, temp);
    if(temp.get(0) == 0){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

And sure enough, it crashes the app, since apparently, the shader didn't compile properly - which is odd, since it is character for character the same shader code I used in the tutorial. So, I tried to grab a log using GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader) right before the above block of code and reading that out using the debugger, but all I get in the string is "". I read about this bug: [glGetShaderInfoLog returns empty string (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588800/glgetshaderinfolog-returns-empty-string-android/8965475#8965475) , but that's over 5 years old, and I would think that it's been fixed by now (especially since I haven't found anything newer on that topic)... or am I still, by any chance, dealing with the same bug? My phone (Moto g4 play) is running on Android Marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was barking up the wrong tree on this one. Here's my mistake:
the second argument to glGetShaderiv shouldn't be the shader type, but rather what you're trying to get (in this case GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS). Sure enough, it compiled correctly, and my problem is somewhere else.